# Registering cascading dependencies

Tags: unity-container

```
_container.RegisterType<TypeA>();
_container.RegisterType<TypeC>(); // TypeC has a dependency to TypeA
_container.RegisterType<TypeD>(); // TypeD has a dependency to TypeA

_container.RegisterType<TypeE>(); // TypeE has a dependencies to TypeC and TypeD
_container.RegisterType<TypeF>(); // TypeF has a dependencies to TypeC and TypeD
```

How do I set this up so that when I create types E and F they both use a new instance of TypeA (indirectly through types C and D) but C and D both use the same TypeA?

If it helps imagine that TypeA is a repository and C and D are services that use that repository. Types E and F are ViewModels that need different repositories but interact with the repository through services C and D.

I imagine I could resolve typeA and then use that instance to resolve the other types but I'm guessing there is a better way, as that seems quite messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to your second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9423533/921321).

By using a `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, when `TypeE` is resolved, `TypeE` and its dependencies `TypeC` and `TypeD` all get the same instance of `TypeA`. When `TypeF` is resolved, a new `TypeA` is resolved, which it and all of its dependencies will share.

`PerResolveLifetimeManager` is one of my favorite things about Unity as an IOC container over others.

Answer (score 0):

If you register TypeA as singleton, all instances requesting objects of TypeA will use the same single reference. When registering the class using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager it will keep the object as singleton until the container is disposed.

```
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

This is the default behavior. To change this, meaning having a new instance every time, as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx) here you need to use a different lifecycle:

```
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
```

Comment: This is my problem I dont want it to be a singleton. I need TypeE to use a different TypeA then TypeF.

Comment: @foo I've provided an answer which doesn't create a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy.. you should try to name your instance and used InjectionConstructor to provide the instance you want. Something like that :

_container.RegisterType

_container.RegisterType(
                new InjectionConstructor(_container.Resolve("MainRepository")));